# MySQL and phpMyAdmin - export doesn't always export everything

Tags: mysql, php, web-hosting

So here's the thing. On completely different hosts, installations, operating systems and versions of MySQL and PHP (and phpMyAdmin) (but always on a host I'm visiting over the Internet), I've found an interesting situation:

When I try to export a database table (MyISAM or InnoDB) which has "a lot" of data in it, using compression (gzip, zip, it doesn't matter), the file generated isn't complete.

I've put "a lot" in quotes, because it ranges from 1 000 rows to 30 000 rows, depending on the platform. It seems the actual amount is irrelevant.

I have worked around this problem by running mysqldump on the command line and then compressing the output, but I wanted to hear from the community whether this is a known issue, or if it has something to do with the crap bandwidth we have in South Africa, which was recently [beaten by a carrier pigeon](http://www.news24.com/Content/SciTech/News/1132/1bc8b09e39b043928317dc769d4196e4/09-09-2009%2012-23/Pigeon_beats_Telkom).

Comment: This one totally belongs on SF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it's a script time-out issue with phpMyAdmin, or perhaps a file-size limitation of the underlying webserver.

**Update**
On a script-by-script bases, you can add `set_time_limit(0);` at he top and it will override the PHP settings for script timeout to infinite. Any value other than 0 will set it for that many seconds.

Comment: I thought it was file size limit, but it turned out not to be the case. I'm also inclined to think it's a timeout.

Comment: hopefully it's right :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's timeout/browser issue or something similar.

I was working with *phpmyadmin* in **Chrome browser** and it didn't *export* db.

But I **switched to Firefox** and it worked for me.
So **change your browser** and try again!